# How to change the text of a button in side a Gridview of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a button inside a grid view.
The button is in the `<HeaderTemplate>` of a grid view.
The button text is Select All.

- Condition:

When I checked the button Select All then all the check box below to this are checked (In side the grid view).

At that moment the button text should change to Unselected All & the check box
are also unchecked inside the grid view.(Like we shown in the Yahoo Mail or )

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-selectdeselect-checkboxes-in.html

Comment: what the issue is text change or how to select all??

Comment: Are you looking for a server-side or client-side solution?

Comment: I want to change the text of the button to Unselected & when i clicked on the unselected button then all the check boxes are going to be Unchecked. @Neha

Comment: I want server side. @ChrisHardie

Comment: ok, why you tag your question to jquery, if need it do at server side?

Comment: Yes,I want to do it through Server side. @Neha

Comment: @tophan - jquery is client side

Comment: Yes,I know.But I want Server side.. @rtpHarry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change name in that button click :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString().Contains("Un"))
    {
    this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText="UnSelect All";
    }
    else
    {
    this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText="Select All";
    }
}
```

if you want to change name in  checkbox OnCheckedChanged event

```
 protected void Ck_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString().Contains("Un"))
        {
        this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText="UnSelect All";
        }
        else
        {
        this.gvw1.Columns[0].HeaderText="Select All";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

CODE with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cY6La/)

```
$('#ChkSelectAll').click(function () {
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.ChkSelect').prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    $('.ChkSelect').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

& to change text use .val() function where required

And one more

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        var chkboxrow = "#<%=gvpub.ClientID%> input[id*='chkSelection']:checkbox";  
        var chkall =$("input[id$='chkAll']");  
        $(chkall).change(function(){     
            $(chkboxrow).each(function()
            {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
                $(chkall).text('Select All');

            }
            else 
            {
                 $(this).attr('checked', true);  
                 $(chkall).text('Unselect All');
            }       
            });              
       });
    });

    </script>
```

**EDITED**:

For server side, on click of button

```
bool toggle = true;
if (Button1.Text == "Check All") {
    Button1.Text = "Uncheck All";
} else {
    Button1.Text = "Check All";
    toggle = false;
}

foreach (checkbox in first column) {
    chk.Selected = toggle;
}
```

**NOTE**: try to use update panel or take care of postback issue. Better to use client side for such functionality